# 2008 chevy 2500HD 6.0L

Tags: chevrolet, wiring, o2-sensor, silverado

Rear O2 sensor plug on drivers side has been torn off of the main harness leaving only two wires left to go to the O2 sensor.  O2 sensor appears to have had 4 wires coming from it.  How do I rewire from the main harness, when I replace the old O2 sensor?  I have peeled back the covering on the main harness but can only find two wires.  Please advise!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! To my knowledge there's going to be four wires. Two are the ground/power to the heater, while the other two are the overall ground for the O2 and the sensor wire. The sensor you describe should be B1S2, if I'm not mistaken. [I think this should be a wiring diagram for it.](https://ls1tech.com/forums/attachments/pcm-diagnostics-tuning/172834d1238279775-wiring-diagram-04-z06-o2-s1b1.png)

Answer (score 1):

Along with Paul's diagram below, the second diagram should get the job done.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The only wires that are coming out of the harness to the O2 sensor are Purple/White and Tan/White.  I cannot find the other two brown wires in the harness, per your drawing.  I pulled the covering back from the harness but I cannot see where the wires were pulled apart.